# Not able to access json Object key

Tags: json, angular

I have a json object as below:

**Json**

`{error: false, message: [,…]}`

Inside message:

```
{convid: "5aeab8a0e5dd7c55942a7ce7", recipient: "Akhil Sindhwani", seen: false, from: "Miti Desai",…}
```

> convid : "5aeab8a0e5dd7c55942a7ce7" from : "Miti Desai" messages :
>   "asdsad" recipient : "Akhil Sindhwani" seen : false subject : "sasas"
>   updatedAt : "2018-05-03T07:22:09.367Z"

I am working in Angular and above is the response I get from http service.

Service function:

```
  getUserMessages() {
    console.log("getUserMessages");

    this._mailingService.getMessages()
      .subscribe(conversations => {
        this.messageData = conversations
        if (conversations) {
          console.log( this.messageData);
          this.messageData = conversations



        }


      })
      , error => {
      console.log("Error");

       },
       () => {
        // THIS IS EXECUTED AFTER THE SUBSCRIBE COMPLETES
        console.log( 'this.messageData');
        console.log( this.messageData);

     }
  }
```

In code above I get a response in conversation which I get that json object.
I put that object in message data.

In html I tried to parse message data as follow:

```
  <div id="messageMenu">
        <ul>
          <li class='msgBody' *ngFor = "let message of messageData.message">

              <div class="msgListingContainer1">
                <div class="senderImg">
                  <img src="../../../../assets/images/profile1.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style=" display:inline-block" class="msgListingContainer2">
                <span  style=" display:inline-block" class="senderName">{{message.recipients}}</span>
                <span class="msgTimestamp">5:13pm</span>
                <p class="msgheading"><span>Hey alex pretty cool new track you got..</span></p>
              </div>

          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

But I get this error message:

> MessageMenuComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'message' of undefined

I am trying to fetch a key from json and then loop it using ngFor directive it. It is simple, I have done this before.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Response from API call]

**Update**

Not sure how it worked.
Didn't change anything in component file.

Changed html to:

```
<div id="messageMenu">
        <ng-container *ngIf="showConversations;else noCnvrstns" >
          <ul>
              <li class='msgBody' *ngFor = "let message of messageData">
                  <div class="msgListingContainer1">
                    <div class="senderImg">
                      <img src="../../../../assets/images/profile2.jpg">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style=" display:inline-block" class="msgListingContainer2">
                    <span  style=" display:inline-block" class="senderName">{{message.recipient}}</span>
                    <span class="msgTimestamp">{{ message.updatedAt |  date:'hh:mm a' }}</span>
                    <p class="msgheading">{{message.messages}}</p>
                  </div>
              </li>
        </ul>


    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #noCnvrstns>
        <div class="noConversations">No conversations to show</div>
    </ng-template>
    </div>
```

Started getting response.

I didn't understand when messages were in message key of json object then how I able to fetch them out of conversations directly but working for me.

Not adding answer as question itself is ambiguous.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use safe navigation `?` in case of asnyc calls fetching data. it will not alow angular to throw an error.

Try this -

```
 <li class='msgBody' *ngFor = "let message of messageData?.message">
```

Also at the time of declaration typecaste `messageData: any`.

Comment: Thanks for response Pardeep jain. Not getting any errors now. But no output.

Comment: @Simer just try to print whole data in HTML using `{{messageData?.message | json}}`

Comment: it prints null for fractions of second and then no output.

Comment: then check your response from backend

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` file is malformed.

How you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp):

> In JSON, keys must be strings, written with double quotes

Insert double quotes around your keys, this will probably fix the problem.